# Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdByCode() on boolean in

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm getting this error in two areas - one on the frontend here...

http://82.147.12.196/~securato/besafe-izi-up-x3-fix

Click the 'first to review this product' link on the above page and you will see of them.

The other occurs in the admin when accessing `Review>Manage Ratings`.  This error reads...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdByCode() on boolean in /home/securato/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/RatingController.php on line 154

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add that line 154 in your question please?

Comment: Sorry, this is the link for the first error http://www.securatot.co.uk/axkid-minikid-214

Comment: Line 154 is....

        Mage::register('entityId', Mage::getModel('rating/rating_entity')->getIdByCode('product'));

Comment: Could you dump what is `Mage::getModel('rating/rating_entity')`? Seems weird that it would just be a boolean. Is it something you wrote or are you using base Magento functionalities?

Comment: No, haven't touched this during development.  In fact it was working on a dev space here...  http://dev---securatot---dev.co.uk/izi-go-modular-black-cab

Comment: I get the error on line 53 not 154.

Comment: There are two errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. PhilW, how did you solve this?. Can your share it with the community?. I'm investigating about the issue and did the following:

1. Reinstall the rating tables.
2. Compare my tables content with a fresh installation and both match perfectly.
3. Overwrite completely app/code/core/Mage/Rating

And is still not working. It always return Call to a member function getIdByCode() on boolean in ....app/code/core/Mage/Rating/Model/Rating/Entity.php on line 4

..Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdByCode() on boolean ..RatingController.php on line 154

Thanks!